# How to populate a <select> tag with options using jQuery Select2 plugin in Struts 2

Tags: java, jquery, json, struts2, jquery-select2

I'm trying to populate a `<select>`tag with [Struts2 JSON](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json) and [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/). Server is returning a JSON like this:

```
{"orphanets":[{"idDiagOrphanet":11509,"nomDiagOrphanet":"FACOMATOSIS CESIOFLAMMEA"},{"idDiagOrphanet":21782,"nomDiagOrphanet":"AUTOINFLAMMATION"}]}
```

How can I format/parse the result to make it work? I know it expects `id` and `text` fields, but cant get it working:

```js
 $("#selCodOrphanet").select2({
    quietMillis: 300,
    placeholder: "Buscar diag. Orphanet...",
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    ajax: {
        url: '../json/getOrphanets',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
          return {
            term: term
          };
        },                  
        results: function (data, page) {
          return { results: data.orphanets };
        },
        id: function(item) {
          return item.idDiagOrphanet; 
        },
        formatResult: function(item) { 
            return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + item.nomDiagOrphanet + "</div>"; 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What results are returned from the ajax call?

Comment: At the end I just added "getId" and "getText" methods to the "Orphanet" object. I didn't want to parse the full json answer again. Anyway I still dont know why "id: function(item)" and "formatResult: function(item)" didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a bit searching but didn't found `id: function(item) {`

Anyways, here's a quick-fix

1. Consider the response as a normal string
2. replace `idDiagOrphanet` with `id` and `nomDiagOrphanet` with `text` and then return this string instead of `return { results: data.orphanets };`

Here's another way : 
[Modifying a JSON object by creating a New Field using existing Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540071/modifying-a-json-object-by-creating-a-new-field-using-existing-elements)

```
var ornts= data.orphanets;
var new_obj ;
for(var i=0; i<data.orphanets.length; i++){
    var person = persons[i];
    new_obj.push({
        id: ornts.idDiagOrphanet,
        text: ornts.nomDiagOrphanet,
    });
}

return new_obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $("#selCodOrphanet").select2({
    placeholder: "Buscar diag. Orphanet...",
    minimumInputLength: 4,
    ajax: {
        url: '<s:url namespace="/json" action="getOrphanets"/>',
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term, page) {
          return {
            term: term
          };
        },                  
        results: function (data, page) {
          return { results: data.orphanets };
        },
        id: function(item) {
          return item.idDiagOrphanet; 
        },
        formatResult: function(item) { 
            return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + item.nomDiagOrphanet + "</div>"; 
        }
        escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; }  
    }
});
```

Added the qualified URL mapping to `getOrphanets` action with namespace `/json`. Corresponding configuration should be made. Don't escape markup since you are displaying HTML in results.